# Логгирование двух независимых процессов в один файл в Python

Tags: python, логирование

Добрый день. У меня есть два процесса, одно из них клиент, другое сервер. Мне необходимо чтобы они логгировались вдвоем в один файл. В итогу в лог файле я должен получить что-то такое:

```
bot1>sending message: hi!
bot2>got message: hi!
bot2>sending answer: hello you too
bot1>got message: hello you too
bot1>sending message: green
bot2>got message: green
bot2>sending answer: bonjourna
bot1>got message: bonjourna
bot1>got wrong message, expected: apple, received: bonjourna
bot1>sending message: green
bot2>got message: green
bot2>sending answer: bonjourna
bot1>got message: bonjourna
bot1>got wrong message, expected: apple, received: bonjourna
```

Я решил использовать следующий алгоритм:

1.Сервер открывает файл, записывает туда свой лог, затем закрывает файл

2.Клиент открывает файл, записывает туда свой лог, затем закрывает файл

3.Сервер открывает файл, записывает туда свой лог, затем закрывает файл

....
Ну и так они делают до победного конца.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой алгоритм?

Comment: сделать отдельный сервер для логирования и пусть он пишет в файл. а  клиент и сервер посылают ему то, что надо записать в файл.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import threading

def log_write(text: str, file='log.txt', lock=threading.Lock()):
    lock.acquire()  # закрывает lock
    try:
        with open(file, 'a') as f:  # открывает файл
            f.write(text)  # записывает туда свой лог
    finally:  # затем закрывает файл
        lock.release()  # затем открывает lock


class B(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):  # логгировались вдвоем в один файл
        [log_write('{}>{}\n'.format(self.name, a)) for a in range(20)]

B().start()  # У меня есть два процесса
B().start()  # У меня есть два процесса
```

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз открывать и закрывать файл - очень расточительно по отношению к ресурсам компьютера. Гораздо лучше в каждом из процессов держать файл открытым постоянно (в режиме `a`) и писать туда по мере необходимости.

Для удобства логирования вы можете использовать библиотеку [Polog](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog). Таким образом вам не придется писать много низкоуровневого кода, включая синхронизацию между процессами как в данном случае. Устанавливается она так:

```
$ pip install polog
```

Попробуем ее применить:

```
from polog import log, config, file_writer


config.add_handlers(file_writer("some_file.log"))

log("some text")
```

В данном примере мы записали в файл `some_file.log` какой-то вот такой текст:

```
[2022-10-31 23:14:52.083730] |    1    | UNKNOWN | MANUAL | "some text" | where: ?
```

Вы можете размещать логирующий код в нескольких процессах одновременно. Если вам потребуется ротация логов, безопасная при многопроцессном логировании в один и тот же файл, можно передать соответствующие аргументы при создании обработчика:

```
file_writer("some_file.log", rotation="200 megabytes >> archive", lock_type="thread+file")
```

Через данный обработчик логи будут записываться в файл `some_file.log`, а когда он будет заполняться до 200 мегабайт, файл будет переноситься в директорию `archive`. Кроме того, здесь устанавливается порядок блокировок, гарантирующий безопасность при ротации из нескольких процессов сразу.